# Why does putting this liftIO in a function work, but calling directly doesnt?

Tags: haskell

I am seeing some weird behavior involving monad instances. I am writing a snap application and in one of my handlers, it won't compile unless I make a function.

Calling `withManager` directly in my handler like this:

```
authenticateLanding :: Handler App App ()
authenticateLanding = do
    req <- getRequest
    oir <- liftIO $ withManager $ OpenId.authenticateClaimed (convertParams req)
    writeBS (fromString $ show oir)
```

causes this compile time error

```
openIDTrial.hs:120:25:
    No instance for (Control.Monad.Trans.Control.MonadBaseControl
                       IO m1)
      arising from a use of `withManager'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for
      (Control.Monad.Trans.Control.MonadBaseControl IO m1)
    In the expression: withManager
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `withManager $ OpenId.authenticateClaimed (convertParams req)'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      oir <- liftIO
             $ withManager $ OpenId.authenticateClaimed (convertParams req)
```

However, if I put it in a function, then I dont get that error

```
claim params = liftIO $ withManager $ OpenId.authenticateClaimed (params)

authenticateLanding :: Handler App App ()
authenticateLanding = do
    req <- getRequest
    oir <- claim (convertParams req)
    writeBS (fromString $ show oir)
```

Something about this doesn't make sense since the claim function doesn't look to be adding any extra information for the compiler.

Comment: This may have something to do with the Monomorphism restriction. Try compiling the second version with -XNoMonomorphismRestriction flag and see what happens.

Comment: Sometimes compiler cannot correctly infer the type of an expression, most often when some extensions make type inference incomplete or undecidable. Try adding the proper type for `liftIO ...` expression manually, like `oir <- liftIO .... :: TheProperType`, that could help.

Comment: Add a type signature to `claim` to work around the monomorphism restriction, if @sabauma helped.